# PHP: How to view product details in a separate page without having to create a new file for each product?

Tags: php, mysql

So I've created a market place page that lists all products from a database. They each have buttons to view their details (price, description, etc.) but I don't know how to let the user view the details without creating a new php page for each product.

I've tried using `$_GET` (for example, the url would read `www.websitename.com/page.php?productname=name`), but as I need to pass variable for prices as well, I can't use `GET` or a user could modify prices within the url. I've also tried using `POST`, but I would like the user to be able to bookmark or refresh the page without the variables clearing. I've tried setting `$_SESSION` variables for things like prices to avoid this issue, but as the session variables are still inevitably defined by `POST` or `GET`, I still run into both issues listed previously.

I've also tried using `SQL queries` so that the prices are received on demand from a database when the page (`viewproduct.php`) is loaded, and it searches for the product name that matches the `$_GET['name']` variable, but the products are stored by category in different tables, and I can't check against all tables because they don't have equal dimensions.

So my question is simple: what is the standard for doing something like this? How can I write php code so that a user can bookmark or refresh a page with product information, without being able to edit any of the variables, and without me having to create a file for each and every product?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm confused by "I've tried using $_GET (for example, the url would read www.websitename.com/page.php?productname=name), but as I need to pass variables for prices as well, I can't use GET or a user could modify prices within the url." - why does it matter what price people put in the url as surely that's a query value?  You wouldn't update the database with that value so if they specify a price search value that doesn't exist they'll get nothing back as a result.

Comment: pass things like id and category in the querystring - use these $_GET variables to help build the sql statement that fetches the record for that product

Comment: you got to have to use at least one of these to pass your values ($_GET) is the best choice for this

Comment: I think the best way is to use the "get" method. In your URL you need to pass only the id (unique id) of your product. After in your other page (product details), you have the id of the product and you just need to make a SQL request to have informations of the product.

Comment: Bro, you can use a template page to show uniformity  your output

Comment: The problem with using id's to build a query is that I have different sized tables to check against. For example, if a product is a toy, but I want to check for its price against a database without hardcoding the type of product, I would have to check against the toys table, tools table, videos table, etc. Something like: "SELECT * FROM toys, tools, videos WHERE productname = '$name'";

Comment: category parameter and product id parameter to the url

Comment: Perhaps consider redoing your database structure to merge all the products are in one table with a primary category id?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can link and change everything corresponding to your products. For example, you can link your images this way:

```
echo("<img src=../imgs/" . $_GET['product_name'] . " alt=". $_GET['product_name'] . "/>");
```

And display in the same way every information your have in your database such as comments corresponding to your product, presentation, price, reviews, ranking, etc...

Comment: missing a `]` from `$_GET['product_name'`